# Elegant way to get value from a list of keys in a nested array in python3?

Tags: python-3.x

Consider a dictionary that has the following nested structure:

```
d = {"a0": {"b0": {"c0": 0}, "b1": 1}, "a1": 2}
```

What would be a fast and elegant way to go from a list of keys like `["a0", "b0", "c0"]` to its value `d["a0"]["b0"]["c0"]`, in a general way?

In other words, is there a way to make the following expression a one-liner:

```
val = 0
for k in key_list:
    val = val[key]
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't understand, you want to iterate through all possible keys? To get just a value you can do what you wrote: ```d["a0"]["b0"]["c0"]```

Comment: No, I want to pass the keys in order using a list, just like in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

This I think would be pretty elegant:

```py
def dict_get(d, param):
    if(len(param)>0 and len(d)>0):
        return dict_get(d.get(param[0], {}), param[1:])
    else:
        return d

d = {"a0": {"b0": {"c0": 0}, "b1": 1}, "a1": 2}

ind=["a0", "b0", "c0"]

print(dict_get(d, ind))
```